# Navbar collapse navigation not functioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am hoping someone can help me figure out why the collapse in my Bootstrap navbar isn't working.  From what I have seen from the Bootstrap examples, it should work.  When I view the page on a mobile device or just shrink the window, the nav links collapse as they should, but the button to expand it does not show up.

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        <a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="/images/logo.png"></a> </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="navbar-right"><a href="/contact">CONTACT</a></div>
        <div class="navbar-right"><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></div>
        <div class="navbar-right"><a href="/ourteam">OUR TEAM</a></div>
        <div class="navbar-right"><a href="/work">WORK</a></div>
        <div class="navbar-right"><a href="/services">SERVICES</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

EDIT

I went through the comments and checked everything.  There was an issue with jquery not loading, but I resolved that.  Still happening though.

Comment: Have you included bootstrap.js ?

Comment: Did you checked your console for errors

Comment: check whether any other element's container is on top of "button" to expand in mobile screen.?

Comment: It's look like javascript confliction. check your console for errors and include js in proper sequence.

Comment: Checked all.  The js is included, the console shows no errors, I even removed everything but the nav bar to make sure nothing was covering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data target in the button is `.navbar-ex1-collapse` but you have not included that in `<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">` Include that and try out.

Comment: Yep, looks like that was it.  Thanks.  Still not looking right, but at least I can see it now.  I should be able to work it out from here.

Comment: Yep, figured out how to get it to behave how I wanted.  Thanks again for your help!